# Flutter app error -- RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#0bf43 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Tags: flutter

```
Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#0bf43 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1687 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was
    Padding 
lib\Reset.dart:18
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPadding#0b7cf relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1687 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was
    ListView 
lib\Reset.dart:15
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#393f1 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1687 pos 12: 'hasSize'
The relevant error-causing widget was
    ListView 
lib\Reset.dart:15
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 549 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was
    ListView 
lib\Reset.dart:15
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
The getter 'scrollOffsetCorrection' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: scrollOffsetCorrection
The relevant error-causing widget was
    ListView 
lib\Reset.dart:15
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
```

[Code Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Df1zO.png)

This is my code, when I run it, it show these error above, and the screen goes white. How can I correctly resolve this issue?
[Run Device screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEdhI.png)

Comment: Pls don't attach screenshot of code. Copy paste full code of `ResetPassword` class.

Answer (score 16):

Try wrapping your parent widget in `Expanded()` or add `shrinkWrap: true` before your `ListView` builder